# How can make the two buttons to be center when I use ConstraintLayout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I hope to make two buttons on the center of screen just like Image A when I use Code A, but in fact the two button located on the left screen just like Image B, what error code do I made in my Code A? I know that I can do it by adding a Guideline control, but why can't the Code A do it? Thanks!

**Image A**

[image]

**Image B**

[image]

**Code A**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnAddEdit"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/adView">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            style="@style/myTextMedium"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Backup Name" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddEdit"
        style="@style/myTextMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="One"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLefttOf="@+id/btnCancel"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        style="@style/myTextMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="Two"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/btnAddEdit"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

To Cheticamp:

Thanks!

Code AA works well, why can I delete the `app:layout_constraintRight_toLefttOf="@+id/btnCancel"` ?

**Code AA**

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddEdit"
        style="@style/myTextMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="One"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnCancel"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />
```

Code BB works well , why can I replace `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"`  with `app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"`

**Code BB**

```
  <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        style="@style/myTextMedium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="Two"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnAddEdit"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"   
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
  />
```

And more, could you tell me what are different between `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` and `app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"`

Comment: "Start" corresponds to "left" for a left-to-right [LayoutDirection](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LayoutDirection.html) (LTR). "End" is the right side for LTR layouts. "Start" and "end" flip sides when the layout direction is right-to-left meaning that "start" is then "right" and "end" becomes left. I suggest not using right/left but start/end for your layouts unless the Android Studio designer complains which it won't.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that I should always to use `app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"` instead of `app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"` ?

Comment: Yes, that is preferable. My sense is that left/right will eventually be phased out and is supported now for backward compatibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is the corrected XML that will lay out like "Image A" without any hard coding or margins:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnAddEdit"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/adView">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Backup Name" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="One"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/btnCancel"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLefttOf="@+id/btnCancel"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
        android:text="Two"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/btnAddEdit" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

The key thing to do is to constrain button "one" to the left side of the parent and button two to the right side. A packed chain is create between the two buttons. See [Chains](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#Chains) in the documentation.

You can set a start/end margin on the buttons to separate them while maintaining the centering.

> CHAIN_PACKED -- the elements of the chain will be packed together. The horizontal or vertical bias attribute of the child will then affect the positioning of the packed elements

Comment: Thanks, could you have a look at the modified question?

Answer (score 0):

For your button try using this attribute for button one

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.4"
```

and for button two use

```
app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.6"
```

Comment: Thanks! but I think that your code can't fit all dimension screen. it's a hard code.

Comment: Its not hard code check this https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html#CenteringPositioning

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your code, it should be working now!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnAddEdit"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/adView">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Backup Name" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnAddEdit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
        android:text="One"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLefttOf="@+id/btnCancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCancel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="80dp"
        android:text="Two"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, but your code android:layout_marginEnd="80dp" is hard code